# How change static select on object select?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.6

I can select data from table using for example code below

```
$ab = Order::where('user_id', 2);
    ->where('stock_id', 30);
    ->get();     
dd($ab);
```

And is ok, but i need create search condition and i would like create query like this below

```
$ab = new Order();
!empty($request->user_id) ? $ab->where('user_id', $request->user_id) : false;
!empty($request->stock_id) ? $ab->where('stock_id', $request->stock_id) : false;
dd($ab->get());
```

And not working. Could anyone give me a hint ?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
$ab = new Order();
```

you can use:

```
$ab = Order::query();
```

to start new query.

You can also use `when` closures like so:

```
$ab = Order::query()->when($request->filled('user_id'), function($q) {
   $q->where('user_id', $request->user_id)
})->when($request->filled('stock_id'), function($q) {
   $q->where('stock_id', $request->stock_id)
})->get();
dd($ab);
```